# Connect session middleware - regenerate vs. reload

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am trying to get a hang of Connect's Session middleware, and I would like to know the difference between: Session.regenerate() vs Session.reload().

Specifically, I checked the docs, and no explanation was given about what session reload actually does. Similarly, I am also confused about Session.save() method. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing the source code for the 2 functions:

**store.js**

```
Store.prototype.regenerate = function(req, fn){
  var self = this;
  this.destroy(req.sessionID, function(err){
    self.generate(req);
    fn(err);
  });
};
```

and

**session.js**

```
defineMethod(Session.prototype, 'reload', function reload(fn) {
  var req = this.req
    , store = this.req.sessionStore;
  store.get(this.id, function(err, sess){
    if (err) return fn(err);
    if (!sess) return fn(new Error('failed to load session'));
    store.createSession(req, sess);
    fn();
  });
  return this;
});
```

I read it as "get the session if it exists or create one" vs "destroy the previous and give me a new one".

Comment: Both of these links are now broken.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I just edited the answer with the code snippets from the current location of the repository, this should help anyone who stumbles onto this answer